# PouchDb replicate a document over bluetooth

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, pouchdb

I have two pouch databases on two mobiles phones A and B. I have a document on A and I want to replicate it to B, of course I can't use the classic replication API because I'm on a bluetooth network.

So I get the document on A:

```
_id: 'myDocument'
_rev: '1-651b13c02859d5b90a6043193e7bc078'
content: {...}
```

And I send it over bluetooth to B.

When I put the document on B I have a conflict error, except if I set the document _rev to null. I'd like to create the document on B exactly like A, with same revision, how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [pouchdb-replication-stream](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream) and related tools like pouchdb-load. These tools allow you to dump a PouchDB database to a string, and then load that string into another PouchDB database. Since it's just a string, you can send it over Bluetooth or whatever transfer protocol you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer nlawson, but is there a way to replicate only a single document ? Without dumping the whole db ?

Comment: If I dump whole db I'll have performance issues when it becomes too heavy, and I'm looking to sync only documents that must be.

Comment: Yes, pouchdb-replication-stream supports [filtered replication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream#dbdumpstream--opts).